# SSIS: How can one initiate the whole process again if a task fails

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

Well, I am a newbie to SSIS. Is there any way to go to task "Delete zip files", when my second task "Download zip files" fails?

[image]

Comment: do you want it to run automatically...? can you be please clear

Comment: yeah it will run automatically.....It's like a scheduler.....But I want to repeat the process if some task fails

Comment: then use the agent job in SQL, in step options, make as ->when task fails go to this package